# How to make multiple threads execute sequentially?

Tags: c, multithreading

I want to have multiple threads execute sequentially.
Because I need to do some work on CPU cache. So I need two threads to run on different CPU cores. Two physical CPU cores share the Last level cache. My job is to operate Last level cache

This can be achieved with `pthread_attr_setaffinity_np`.

This can be achieved by locking.
But when implementing it, I found it easy to have two threads execute sequentially.

```
void trasmitter_func(void *addr){

   while(1){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
      if (sequence  == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
      }
      if(sequence == -1){
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
        break;
      }
      printf("trasmitter start\n");
      sequence = 0;
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);

   }
   
}

void receiver_func(void *addr) {  


  for(int i=0;i<SAMPLE_NUMBER;i++){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&lock1);
      if (sequence == 1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond1, &lock1);
      }
      // printf("receiver start\n");
      sequence = 1;

      pthread_cond_signal(&cond1);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock1);
  }
  sequence = -1;
}
```

But when implementing three threads, I need to use two `locks` and two `pthread_cond_signal`. And the controls are complicated. I'm curious, is there some simple implementation here that would allow three  or more than three threads to execute sequentially?

I can simply pass some tags and functions to ensure their execution.

```
execute_func_sequence(0, func_1);
execute_func_sequence(1, func_2);
execute_func_sequence(2, func_3);
execute_func_sequence(3, func_4);
```

Then fun_1 to fun_4 will be executed sequentially.

This seems to be difficult to implement using locks and signals.

What I want to emphasize is: each is not executed once.

```
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
receiver start
trasmitter start
```

The execution result of the above sample code is as follows. I need to execute two threads non-stop sequentially.

I want to run multiple threads in this form.

```
func_1(){
   for(int i=0;i <SAMPLE_NUMBER; i++){
       do work1;
       // block  and enter func_2;
   }
   end = true;
}

func_1(){
   while(1){
       do work2;
       if(end)
           break
       // block  and enter func_3;
   }
}

func_1(){
   while(1){
       do work3;
       if(end)
           break
       // block  and enter func_1;
   }
}
```

Finally got this working.

```
   work1,
    work2,
    work3,
    work1,
    work2,
    work3,
    work1,
    work2,
    work3,
    ...
    work1,
    work2,
    work3,
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this is serial code, I think you would need to a synchronization primitive for each thread.

Comment: read up on semaphores

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen semaphores will not help at all.

Comment: You want FIFO mutex and you have to implement it yourself. There are many possible solutions.

Comment: Or you can just skip the threads and use a for loop. Astronomically faster and in this case you don't care about the sole purpose of using threads to begin with anyway.

Comment: thank you! But in my experiments, the reason for using multithreading is that I want to bind them to different CPU cores to run.  thank you! But in my experiments, the reason for using multithreading is that I want to bind them to different CPU cores to run. Through the pthread_attr_setaffinity_np function.

Comment: @Gerrie why while(1) if you want to execute one time only ?

Comment: It is not executed once. Instead, execute SAMPLE_NUMBER times. 
It can be seen that only sequence == -1, the break is performed. That is, the end of the for loop of receiver_func will make sequence =-1.

Comment: You should make your use case and all requirements clear in your question. What is the advantage of running two or more threads *sequentially* instead of doing all work in one thread? To me this use case does not make sense.

Comment: I need to do some work on CPU cache. So I need two threads to run on different CPU cores. Two physical CPU cores share the Last level cache. My job is to operate Last level cache.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this purpose. The text of your question should explain how you want your 3 or more threads to interact and how they should run in multiple cycles.

Comment: After your edit it is still not yet clear how you want the 4 functions to interact. Add a textual description of what you want to achieve. I suggest to create a [mre] for 2 threads, i.e. a minimal program we can compile and run. Based on the (yet to be specified) requirements we can try to extend the example code for 4 threads.

Comment: The way I would do this is to call `pthread_join()` on the first thread before launching the second thread, then call `pthread_join()` on the second thread before launching the third thread, and so on.  Not that it makes a whole lot of sense to do that, since you could get the same behavior simply by not launching threads at all, and rather just calling the thread-entry-function as a normal function.

Comment: Re, "I need to do some work on CPU cache...My job is to operate Last level cache." You're going to need to expand that explanation some before anybody can help you. What does "work on...cache" mean? Why do you think you need to do it? What does "operate...cache" mean? It's your _job?_ As in, your employer told you, "You need to operate the last level cache?"

Answer (score 0):

A possible way of implementing what you want is:

```
void func_1() {
    // do work...
    sem_post(&thread2_sem);
}

void func_2() {
    sem_wait(&thread2_sem);
    // do work...
    sem_post(&thread3_sem);
}

void func_3() {
    sem_wait(&thread3_sem);
    // do work...
    sem_post(&thread4_sem);
}

void func_4() {
    sem_wait(&thread4_sem);
    // do work...
}

int main() {
    sem_init(&thread2_sem, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&thread3_sem, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&thread4_se,, 0, 0);
    NEW_THRAD(func_1)
    NEW_THRAD(func_2)
    NEW_THRAD(func_3)
    NEW_THRAD(func_4)
}
```

As you can see, every thread is locked in some semaphore, and the previous thread is responsible for unlocking it.

The program starts with all the semaphores initialized to zero and, on each step, one semaphore gets incremented in order to activate the next thread, which will immediately decrement it.

All semaphores must go back to zero in case there's "another batch". i.e.: the threads are ready to process another order (whatever that means).

Note the example functions don't have a loop, y assume you would want something like:

```
void func_3() {
    while (g_running) {
        sem_wait(&thread3_sem);

        // do work...

        sem_post(&thread4_sem);
    }
}
```

In this case, you may need something similar to wake up `func_1`.

Comment: very poor solution as if you wnt to change the order you need to rewrite the code

Comment: @0___________ oh yes. this is as bad as it gets.

Comment: Re, "every thread is locked in some mutex, and the previous thread is responsible for unlocking it." You can't do that with pthreads. You can't do it with things called "mutex" or "lock" In _most_ multi-threading languages and libraries. If you want one thread to unlock what another thread locked, then you need to use something that traditionally is called "semaphore." I don't remember though whether [posix semaphores](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) are based on heavy-weight IPC system calls, or whether they're lightweight things you'd use within a single process.

Comment: you re right. thanks for pointing this out. will fix